# Como ocultar query post vazia?

Tags: css, wordpress

Criei um Query post pra uma determinada categoria

```
<div class="querypost-home" id="conteudo-home4">

<?php
$args = array(
'category_name'=>'oportunidades',
'numberposts'=>1,
'offset'=>3
);

$my_posts = get_posts($args);

if( $my_posts ):
foreach( $my_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>


<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

   <div class="img1"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(870,420)); ?></a></div>

 <?php endif; ?>

<div class="titulo-query-home"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php  title_lenght(40) ?></p></a></div>

  <div class="resumo-query-home"><p><?php echo get_excerpt(160); ?></p></div>
<?php 
endforeach; 
else:
?>
<p></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- query post -->
```

Coloquei uma class nesse query pra eu poder colocar um estilo legalzinho nesses posts da query.
Sendo que, quando eu não adiciono nenhum post, o BG da query ainda fica aparecendo, mas sem conteúdo.
Alguem sabe como esconder os query quando não tem nenhum posts nos offset dele ?

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o seletor CSS `:empty` seja útil nesse caso.

Seria assim:

```
.sua-classe:not(:empty){
    background-color: black;
}
```

Um jsFiddle funcionando para exemplificar:

http://jsfiddle.net/j5jawp49/

Mais informações sobre o `:empty`:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use a seguinte condição para que a classe só apareça se houver conteúdo:

```
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```